# function does not end in a return statement

Tags: c, string, return

I am new to C but I know the fundamentals of coding. However, I cannot see why the compiler returns the error:

> function ".." does not end in a return statement !

Here is my code:

```
string same_start_end(string s)

{
  char first_letter = string_charat(s, 0);
  string empty = "";
  if( string_length(s) <= 1)
  {
      return s;
  }
  else if (string_length(s) > 1)
  {
      for (int  i = 0; i < string_length(s); i++)
      {
          if( (string_charat(s, i) == first_letter) && (i != 0))
          {
              return string_sub(s, 0,i);
          }
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: "*I cant see why the compiler return this error*" because the compiler is, well, just a compiler.

Comment: Because, it doesn't end in a return statement? It is probably not smart enough to understand that your if-else if is exhaustive. Write if-else.

Comment: @Lundin: "*if-else*": I doubt this helped, as it probaly is not able to predetermine what `string_charat()` will do. But well, again a guessing contest.

Comment: What happens if none of the two `return` statements you have will happen? What happens if the loop just finishes?

Comment: @Lundin I tried to do that, but same problem

Comment: Try some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), and tell your "rubber duck" what happens if the condition inside the loop is never true. What is returned in that case?

Comment: @Lundin string_charat() returns the letter at index i

Comment: @Lundin: It is not exhaustive. When the outer `else` is executed, the loop within it does not always execute the `return`.

Comment: How is this `c`?

Comment: @Deanie: `string` is defined with a `typedef` in code not shown in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler warns that control may reach the end of your non-void function because control may reach the end of your non-void function.

To prevent this you must do one of:

- Disable the compiler warning. (With Clang, the command-line option `-Wno-return-type` does this.) (In C, it is allowed for a non-void function to flow off the end of the function without returning a value provided the caller does not attempt to use the return value.)
- Make it apparent to the compiler that function returns.

There are two paths where it is not clear to the compiler that the function returns.

First, consider:

```
if (string_length(s) <= 1)
   …
else if (string_length(s) > 1)
```

Mathematically, we know that either *x* ≤ 1 or *x* > 1, so “*x* ≤ 1 or *x* > 1” is true. However, the compiler does not know that the first call to `string_length(s)` returns the same value as the second call. So it cannot know that at least one of these conditions is true. It must assume they could both be false, and then control would flow to the end of the function without a `return` statement.

Some compilers have a feature that allows you to declare a function to be *pure*, which would tell the compiler that it returns the same value given the same input and also does not change the program’s state in other ways. If you used that feature, or the compiler could see the definition of `string_length`, it might be able to detect that one of the two conditions is true. However, an easier way to fix this is simply to change `else if (string_length(s) > 1)` to `else`. Then the compiler **knows** that if the `if` clause is not executed, the `else` clause must be.

Second, consider:

```
for (int  i=0; i<string_length(s);i++)
    {
      if( (string_charat(s,i)==first_letter) && (i!=0))
        {
          return string_sub(s, 0,i);
        }
    }
```

This loop can end without the `if` being triggered. There might be no character in `s` that equals the first character, and so the `return` is never executed. Then loop completes and control flows to the end of the function without a `return` statement.

To prevent this, you could insert a `return` statement after the `for` loop. It would return whatever value you want to return when a match is not found.

Answer (score 1):

You only have returns in your `if` and `else if` statements. If both of those fail, you have no return statement. Consider doing and `else` instead of doing an `else if` or having a return statement after all of those.

Edit:

Your for loop isn't returning anything if you iterate through it and it never triggers the if statement

Comment: Having only an `else` won't help as both current `return` statements are conditional. If none of the conditions are true, then the loop will finish and the function will just run out without any unconditional return.

Comment: even if I kept it as if-else, I get the same message !

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You are right. There is a path that has no result if the loop completes and the if never triggers. there needs to be a return statement seperate from that if. And if all else fails and you feel you covered all your bases, put `return 0` at the end of your function

Comment: returning zero is completely wrong as the function promise to return a string :), I see your point but how does the compiler see these possibilities, I mean there is no syntax error

Comment: @Mer_ If there is a possible code path that is unresolved the compiler will catch it. You need to return something at every turn because the function is expecting to return something

Answer (score 0):

When using C and C++, you must be careful when defining the function. By writing  `string`, you are telling the compiler that this function has to return a string. If you don't want to do so, try switching to `void`, as void doesn't return a value. If you want to use void, but still have the external functions know the variables, you should use pointers. In your case, the return is sometimes not excecuted